# JPA Querying for json field in Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA Entity as such:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode; 

@Entity
public class Data {
  @Id
  private Integer id;
  @Lob
  private JsonNode json;
}
```

Is it possible to write JPQL to query the json field values?

Something like this:

```
from Data d where d.json.firstName = :firstName
```

I'm getting this error:

```
QueryException: could not resolve property: firstName
```

Is it possible to configure it to ignore property resolution errors when accessing JsonNode fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you might be able to perform a string match in the `WHERE` clause. More specific JSON search needs to be supported by the database engine. I found this documentation for Oracle DB: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6293 Something like this might work, but still check the documentation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data d
WHERE json_textcontains(d.json, '$.firstName', firstName);
```

Comment: I ended up using `json_value` instead.
`WHERE json_value(d.json, '$.firstName') = :firstName`

Comment: Couldn't find the solution for the SELECT portion though... `json_value` does not work in the SELECT clause, so I have to grab the entire json.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `oracle.sql.json` that does exactly that. You might want to take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/sql/json/package-summary.html